# Graph Closeness - Different result with gephi and NodeXL

Tags: graphs, terminology

I'm writing a JavaScript library for calculating graph measurements such as degree centrality, eccentrality, closeness and betweenness.

In order to validate my library I use two exist applications [Gephi](http://gephi.org) and [NodeXL](http://nodexl.codeplex.com/) to run calculation with them.
The problem is I got what looks like different results.

I build simple graph:

```
  (A) ----- (B)
   |         |
   |         | 
  (C) ----- (D)
```

Gephi gave those results:

```
A ecc=2 close=1.333 bet=0.5
B ecc=2 close=1.333 bet=0.5
C ecc=2 close=1.333 bet=0.5
D ecc=2 close=1.333 bet=0.5
```

NodeXL gave those results:

```
A close=0.25 bet=0.5
B close=0.25 bet=0.5
C close=0.25 bet=0.5
D close=0.25 bet=0.5
```

Note that NodeXL does not calculate eccentrality.

Which one is right?
Are the results really different?

I didn't normalize (or at least not intend to normalize) any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **closeness** of a node in a graph is defined as the reciprocal of the sum of all distances to other nodes.

Since your example is completely symmetric, we only calculate the closeness centrality of $A$.

- distance $A\to B$ is 1
- distance $A\to C$ is 1
- distance $A\to D$ is 2

Therefore the sum of the distances is 4, and the closeness of $A$ is $1/4$. This shows that the NodeXL results are correct. I would advise you to have a look at the manual of Gephi to check how the closeness is computed here. It should be definitely be smaller than 1.

Comment: According to [Gephi](https://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/Closeness_Centrality), they give _"the average distance from a given node to all other nodes in the network."_